# Creating tables with NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, schema

I am attempting to use NHibernate for a new application. The goal is to create tables with NH. I have two questions:

1. How is this done, if it can be done.
2. How does this change my configuration section in the app.config?

Comment: To better answer #2, you may want to provide a code sample of your app.config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking to do a `SchemaExport`

Example:

```
new SchemaExport(cfg).Execute(false, true, false, false);
```

Where `cfg` is your NHibernate configuration object.

This is covered well about 1/3 of the way down on this NHibernate Forge article: http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/your-first-nhibernate-based-application.aspx

The text their reads:

> The fourth line of code uses the SchemaExport helper class of
>   NHibernate to auto-"magically" generate the schema in the database for
>   us. SchemaExport will create the product table in the database and
>   each time you call it it will delete the table and the table data and
>   recreate it.

Answer (score -1):

Look at NHibernate Fluent: http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Getting_started

Comment: How does this answer the question?  Typically in SO you explain the answer and not just link to another page. It helps everybody that way.